# Best video recording & mixing software for Ubuntu

Tags: video, streaming, audio-recording

I'm searching for a quality software for recording video streams and mixing 3 cameras' streams and photos. I need it also for online streaming on a website.

It could be a commercial software, doesn't have to be open source or free. I just don't have a clue if there is something like this. Thanks in advance.

**P.S.** It's for Ubuntu 12.04

**P.S.S.** Maybe my definition is not correct or full, so I have to add - I need the program for live broadcast and recording on the computer at the same time.

Comment: Ok so you changed the sense of you question. I changed the answer. :) If you need further help don't hesitate on contacting me. Good luck!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answer was edited after **Galya** edited the original question. Refer to the list of changes in order to see the difference.

There is difficult to say something specific stand-alone piece of software for Ubuntu and even in MS Based Operating Systems you may find useful the usage of ***several tools at once***. Notwithstanding I am going to try to cover the essentials of broadcasting while saving to disk procedure by using several tools at once in both Windows and Ubuntu.

## Ubuntu related software recipe:

### Ingredients:

1. [Ustream web service account](http://www.ustream.tv) or similar ([Justin.tv](http://www.justin.tv/) and [other
   available](http://alternativeto.net/software/ustream/))
2. A fresh install of [Webcam Studio](https://code.google.com/p/webcamstudio/) (well, it can be secondhand, indeed)
3. 1 or more live video devices, such as webcam, VCR, VTR, etc.
4. Optionally: live audio devices.
5. 1 or more pre-recorded video sources
6. Optionally: pre-recorded audio sources.
7. 1 or more pre-made pictures, graphics, transparent overlays,
   animations, etc.
8. Anything else you wish to include in your broadcast. (who knows!?
   you may wish to include something else, right?)

### The Directions

1. First of all get a good computer, and I mean A GOOD ONE. Core i5 is
   the basement. With enough memory and understand that "enough memory"
   will be OVER 4GB for this recipe. Have in consideration that you are
   going to run several high demanding processes at once, thus the
   majority of the RAM will be consumed at the very launch.
2. Once you've sifted the computer with the proper pieces of software,
   added to the latest Ubuntu OS, we need to start cooking in the next
   order:

   Make sure all your devices are well recognized in the Webcam Studio
   Software. This can be done by checking out how many small icons
   appears in the "Devices section" of Webcam Studio, see the next
   illustration:

   [image]

   As you can see, I have 2 live Devices, I also included several
   Images, a movie and a song by using the "Sources/Add a folder to
   scan" option, so that I can choose between several sources for my
   transmission.

   Once you have all your live devices recognized in the software, make
   sure you include everything you need for the broadcast in the
   Sources section (upper left).
3. Next, let's reach our web based broadcast service. For this example
   I am going to use the Ustream Website and use the "Live" button ("En
   Vivo" for the Spanish Version), as shown in the next screenshot:

   [image]
4. When Clicking the "Live" button, you will be shown with the live
   broadcaster in which you can choose the audio/video sources (by
   clicking the small gear icon), choose the "WebcamStudio video
   device" and you'll be presented with the video output of your Webcam
   Studio software. For this example I have chosen an image from my
   collection with the internal audio source (switchable -of course-
   through the sound preferences). See the next full screen
   illustration:

   [image]
5. And that's it. When you're ready simply hit the "Start Broadcast"
   button (Iniciar broadcast in spanish) and if you wish to keep an
   uploaded version of your broadcast hit also the "Start recording"
   button (Iniciar grabacion in spanish) and you'll be on-air.
6. You can have as many webcams, hi-definition cameras
   (USB/FireWire/iLink/iEEE1394,etc.), video sources (VTR, VCR, TV
   Tuners, etc.) as you wish in each layout and unlimited layouts in a
   single project. Projects can be saved inside of the Webcam Studio so
   that you can bring them back when needed. Of course, you will need
   to first make the devices to work in Ubuntu and be recognized by
   WebcamStudio but I am quite sure that you will find a way to calm
   down when needed and do a great job.

### Serving suggestions

This recipe can be served individually on owned website or via social network (Twitter, Facebook, etc.) by hitting the corresponding buttons: Twitter and Facebook will deliver the proper message to the corresponding services while hitting the link in "Your URL" will take you to a page, where you can gather the proper portions of code (tuneable) that can be used for the embedding of the video player in your own website. See the next screenshot for an example:

[image]

When you finish the broadcast, you will have the recording (if you hit the proper button) to download a ready-to-use video file. Additionally you will be prompted for the ready-to-serve video link which will already be uploaded in the Ustream servers.

## ALWAYS REMEMBER!!!

**To serve it cold and in companion with your favorite drink.**

Some extra useful explanations:

1. **You will need** to use the freshest and latest ingredients, specially the newest Java platform that you
   can get in the market (I am using 7, I think).
2. **If you can't get Java** somehow, you can also run this process with
   OpenJDK or another Java Alternative (IcedTea is doing an awesome
   work also).
3. **If you experience some issues** when launching Webcam Studio, please
   refer to comment 16 in this link for reference on how to patch it:
   http://code.google.com/p/webcamstudio/issues/detail?id=75
4. **Just for the record.** For the examples and illustrations I am using
   a Core i5 CPU M 450 (2.4Ghz x 4) with 4GB RAM in a 64 bit version of
   the Precise Pangolin Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS Operating System and if you
   check, the average system load (lower left corner) of Webcam Studio
   is reading a 100%, which means that you will need AT MINIMUM a
   computer like this to run a broadcast with no problems. (Remember:
   small portions won't satisfy any guests, so make sure you use bigger
   portions for this recipe).
5. **When serving**, make sure you get a glass of 13 years old Havana Club
   for me, just with mineral water, salt, lemon and two ices. :)

Good luck!

Oh! yeah! I almost forget it...

## Windows Based OSs recipe.

Well, this is long enough and I don't feel like writing anymore. So I will only include this recipe on demand. Please drop me a link to a place where you have the proper question in order to continue. Thank you for understanding.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. So it seems that WebCam Studio is a good choice. We have a good computer, but our team uses Windows and it's time for a change. Your answer will help us. Thanks!

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/webcamstudio/ is the new site for webcamstudio. Please update the answer so that other people can find it useful.